# How do i make an OK button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 images and 4 buttons. I want to change the colour of the buttons and background of the images when the buttons are clicked.

```
function button_fn(Obj) 
{
    document.getElementById("div_field").style = "background-color:" + Obj.name;
    document.getElementById("img_id").style = "border-color:" + Obj.name;   
}   

</script>
<body>
<fieldset>
<legend > background color change:</legend>
<div id="div_field">
<img src="home.png" name="img_png" width="200"  />
</div>
<form >
<input type="button"  name="red"  value="Red" id="but1_id" onclick= "button_fn(this)"/>
<input type="button"  name="green" value="Green" id="but2_id" onclick="button_fn(this)"/>
<input type="button"  name="blue" value="Blue" id="but3_id" onclick="button_fn(this)"/>
<input type="button"  name="confirm" value="OK" id="confirm_id" onclick="button_fn(this)"/>
</form>
</fieldset>
<div id="div_image" >
<img src="service2.jpg" id="img_id" name="imag" width="200"border="40" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a confirm box:

```
var r=confirm("Press a button");
if (r==true)
{
  x = "You pressed OK!";
}
else
{
  x = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php

Answer (score 0):

All you need i s aconfirm button

```
var r=confirm("Press a button to choose");
if (r==true){
  x = "You pressed OK!";
}
else{
  x  ="You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function button_fn(Obj) 
{
    Obj.style = "background-color:"+Obj.name;
    Obj.style = "border-color:"+Obj.name;
}
```

An alternative way is following script:

```
function button_fn(Obj) 
{
    objId = Obj.id;
    document.getElementById(objId).style = "background-color:"+Obj.name;
    document.getElementById(objId).style = "border-color:"+Obj.name;
}
```